# Authenticating EWS using Oauth with full_access_as_user

Tags: c#, azure, office365, azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to get an application using EWS to work against O365 with OAuth. I've managed to get it working in the case where I register the app in AAD, and grant it full_access_as_app (Use Exchange Web Services with full access to all mailboxes) in the portal.  The code looks like this:

```
string tokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTID/oauth2/v2.0/token";
string resource = "https://outlook.office365.com";

string appId = "APPID_FROM_AAD";
var context = new AuthenticationContext(tokenUri);
X509Certificate2 cert = GetLocalCertificate(THUMBPRINT);
ClientAssertionCertificate c = new ClientAssertionCertificate(appId, cert);
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, c).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
m_exchangeService.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken);

//all the autodiscover URIs for O365 are the same
m_exchangeService.Url = new Uri(@"https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
m_exchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, m_emailAddress);
```

This seemed a little extreme though.  The application is a back end service, and only needs access to one mailbox (the impersonated user id), so I wanted to change it over to full_access_as_user permissions (Access mailboxes as the signed-in user via Exchange Web Services).  I added the permission to the app, and then added the application to the user, but I got a 401 anytime I tried to operate on the mailbox after impersonation.  I checked the JWT, and while with the original permission I had "full_access_as_app" in the roles, I didn't have any roles assigned this time.

Is there a way I can modify this so that I can have an admin add EWS access to one or more mailboxes in a tenant, or is the only way to get this to work to give an app access to every mailbox on the service?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OAuth authentication for EWS is only available in Exchange as part of Office 365. EWS applications require the "Full access to user's mailbox" permission.

Reference - [Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth)

Comment: Right, I get that you need full access to the mailbox, and I'm OK with that, but I want it to be only ONE mailbox, not all of them.  My question was that if I grant "Use Exchange Web Services with full access to all mailboxes" it works, but if I grant "Access mailboxes as the signed-in user via Exchange Web Services" and then admin-assign the app against a user account, I still can't access that user's mailbox.  Not sure what else needs to be done to delegate the permissions to a mailbox.